# Cheap way to create near constant size range partitions in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database-partitioning

I'm using MySQL 5.7 Percona.

My current design uses naive day-by-day partitioning, which adds new partition for next time period on regular basis.

```sql
CREATE TABLE `foo` (
  ...
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC
PARTITION BY RANGE (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`created_at`)) (
    PARTITION `foo_1640995200` VALUES LESS THAN (1640995200) ENGINE = InnoDB, # 2022-01-01 00:00:00
    PARTITION `foo_1641081600` VALUES LESS THAN (1641081600) ENGINE = InnoDB, # 2022-01-02 00:00:00
    PARTITION `foo_1641168000` VALUES LESS THAN (1641168000) ENGINE = InnoDB  # 2022-01-03 00:00:00
);
```

The issue with that approach is that my data distribution is uneven. Some partitions have 1M rows, some have 50M.
Which leads to another issue - amount of opened tables during some long range selects like `SELECT * FROM foo WHERE created_at > NOW() - INTERVAL 1 YEAR`.

I want to optimize it to simply **extend last partition if amount of rows is below some threshold** instead of creating partition for next day. Like:

```sql
SELECT `table_rows`
FROM `information_schema`.`partitions`
WHERE table_schema = DATABASE()
    AND partition_name = 'foo_1641168000';

-- only 1M rows, no need for new partition, extend existing one:

ALTER TABLE `foo` REORGANIZE PARTITION `foo_1641168000` INTO (
    PARTITION `foo_1641254400` VALUES LESS THAN (1641254400) ENGINE = InnoDB  # 2022-01-04 00:00:00
);
```

However this operation despite being simple range change completly rewrites partition `foo_1641168000` data. Despite the fact that all data from existing partition fit into new definition.
Which is no-go due to table locks and excessive I/O usage.

Is there any way to achieve this **without rewriting data**?

BTW: My hacky idea was to add recent data to another table `foo_recent` and when it grows to certain size install it as partition in `foo` using `EXCHANGE PARTITION .. WITHOUT VALIDATION`. But this is dirty and worse both in terms of performance and syntax - queries must work on tables union or be ran on two tables independently with result merging.

Answer (score 0):

`REORGANIZE` *will* read the 'from' partitions and write the 'to' partitions.  Costly -- unless the 'froms' are empty.

Have a partition called 'future' that is `LESS THAN MAXVALUE` and is 'always' empty.

You are stuck with copying over lots of data.

**Plan A:**

Each night, before midnight, do this if the 'last' partition (before 'future') is getting "big":

```
REORGANIZE last, future 
      INTO last, soon, future;
```

Set the `LESS THAN` (for 'last') to end at midnight tonight.  Set the `LESS THAN` for 'soon' to, say, a month from now.  (This is the only big copy.)

**Plan B:**

The following *may* be a viable alternative.  (I just thought of it; I have *not* tried it.)  Each night, see if the "last" (before "future") is "big enough".  When it is, do these steps (just before each midnight):

1. Use "transportable tablespaces" to remove the big partition from the table.  (Note: a partition is essentially a table, so this action is only touching "meta" information.  I'm pretty sure no *data* is copied.)
2. Turn right around and again use "transportable tablespaces" to put it back into the partitioned table, but with a different LESS THAN -- set to midnight tonight.
3. `REORGANIZE future INTO soon, future;` -- Both of those are empty, so this is quite fast.  (The `LESS THAN` for 'soon' is some time in the future.  I hesitate to make it "MAXVALUE", but that might work and be even simpler.)

If you try it and it works, let me know.  I would like to add it to my [*Partition Maintenance blog*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint)

Comment: Thanks for answer and link to interesting blog."Plan A" is no different than having MAXVALUE one and `REORGANIZE foo_max INTO ( PARTITION foo_whatever_timestamp_it is_now, PARTITION foo_max )` when desired size of foo_max is reached.  "Plan B" as far as I know is not possible in MySQL - you still have to create table with the same partition definitions on temporary instance and that still leads to rewrite of data when partition range is extended.

Comment: After extensive research i found no solution. The main issue is that MySQL rewrites data when no rewrite is necessary because new partition `foo_1641254400` in my example contains whole partition `foo_1641168000`.  I have a feeling that partitioning received very little attention since MySQL 5.0 and lacks basic management options like auto creating / expiring range partitions on given schedule or smarter data distribution like the one discussed here.